# Composer: unresolvable dependencies when installing Silex application

Tags: php, composer-php, silex

I am trying to build a Silex application, with the following requirements

**requirements**

> 1. Yaml configuration
> 2. Doctrine ORM
> 3. Simple User Authorisation

**my composer.json**

```
{     
    "require": {     
        "silex/silex": "~1.2",    
        "symfony/yaml": "2.6.7",    
        "doctrine/dbal": "~2.2",    
        "deralex/yaml-config-service-provider": "1.0.x-dev",    
        "dflydev/doctrine-orm-service-provider": "2.0.*@dev",    
        "jasongrimes/silex-simpleuser": "~1.0"     
    }     
}
```

When I run `composer update`, I get the following

**output**

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove silex/silex v1.2.4
    - Conclusion: don't install dflydev/doctrine-orm-service-provider 2.0.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install dflydev/doctrine-orm-service-provider v2.0.0|remove pimple/pimple v1.1.1|install pimple/pimple v3.0.0
    - Conclusion: don't install pimple/pimple v3.0.0
    - Conclusion: don't install silex/silex v1.2.4
    - Conclusion: don't install silex/silex v1.2.3
    - Conclusion: don't install silex/silex v1.2.2
    - Conclusion: don't install silex/silex v1.2.1
    - Conclusion: don't install pimple/pimple v1.1.1
    - Installation request for dflydev/doctrine-orm-service-provider 2.0.*@dev -> satisfiable by dflydev/doctrine-orm-service-provider[2.0.x-dev, v2.0.0].
    - Installation request for silex/silex ~1.2 -> satisfiable by silex/silex[v1.2.0, v1.2.1, v1.2.2, v1.2.3, v1.2.4].
    - silex/silex v1.2.0 requires pimple/pimple ~1.0 -> satisfiable by pimple/pimple[v1.1.1, 1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.0.2, v1.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: pimple/pimple[v2.1.0, 1.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: pimple/pimple[v2.1.0, v1.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: pimple/pimple[v2.1.0, v1.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: pimple/pimple[v2.1.0, v1.1.0].
    - dflydev/doctrine-orm-service-provider v2.0.0 requires pimple/pimple >=2.1,<4 -> satisfiable by pimple/pimple[v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v3.0.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install pimple/pimple v2.1.1
```

I'm not too familiar with groking the intricasies of composer json file syntax.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two of your dependencies require different versions of `pimple` package:

- silex/silex v1.2.0 requires pimple/pimple ~1.0
- dflydev/doctrine-orm-service-provider v2.0.0 requires pimple/pimple >=2.1

You can switch to latest silex or previous version of doctrine-orm-service-provider to resolve this.

Look at packagist.org to see available versions with their dependencies: [silex](https://packagist.org/packages/silex/silex), [doctrine-orm-service-provider](https://packagist.org/packages/dflydev/doctrine-orm-service-provider).

Comment: How do you fix this then? I have the same issue.